# Cant make multiple copies of a file using shutil python

Tags: python-2.7, file, server, shutil

Following is a python code snippet I am running on my server. I want to replicate a file 'n' times and save with a different name each time. However, whatever value I give for loop I always end up getting a single replica made.

```
import os

import time
import shutil




os.chdir(''server_directory)
src='myFile.jpg'

numberofcopies=10

for i in range(0,numberofcopies):
        print "replicating {0}".format(i+1)

        timestamp=int(round(time.time()))
        dst='{0}.jpg'.format(timestamp)
        shutil.copy2(src, dst)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently using a timeout in the main thread and running the loop infinitely unless Ctrl-C interruption solved my problem.

```
import os

import time
import shutil




os.chdir('server_directory')
src='file to replicate.jpg'


i=0
while True:
        print "replicating {0}".format(i+1)
        timestamp=int(round(time.time()))
        dst='{0}.jpg'.format(timestamp)
        shutil.copy2(src, dst)
        i=i+1
        time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should replicate my file 5 times with different names.

```
import os
import shutil
import os

for r in range(5):

  original = r'transactions.xlsx'
  target = f'Newfile{r}.xlsx'
  shutil.copyfile(original, target)
  print (f'Action: replicating {original} as {target}')
```